# Updating combobox realtime after clicking save button

Tags: vb.net, combobox

```
        ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "iAlert"
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "sMessage"
        ComboBox1.DataSource = DBNull.Value
        ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

How can i update the combobox after clicking save/submit button? vb.net 
I want a fresh data from the database after clicking the save button from another tab(tab2) then display it in the combobox in tab1 without restarting the windows form

Comment: Firstly, set the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` before setting the `DataSource`.  Secondly, setting the `DataSource` to `DBNull.Value` makes no sense.  That represent a database NULL but a single database NULL can't be a data source for a `ComboBox`.  You use `Nothing` in VB to represent no object so if you want to clear the `DataSource` then you set it to `Nothing`.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  What does "updating ComboBox" even mean?  If you mean you want to change the data source then just assign a new object to the `DataSource` property.  If you are saying, without actually saying, that you want to get fresh data from a database then you actually need to query that database and then bind the result as normal.  Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: I want a fresh data from the database after clicking the save button from another tab(tab2) then display it in the combobox in tab1 without restarting the windows form sir.

Comment: So query the database again.  Data won't just arrive by magic.  However you got the data in the first place is how you get data.  If you want new data, do the same thing again.

Comment: After I click save button, the fresh data is not updated in the checkbox. I need to close the win form to refresh it.

Comment: Is it possible to auto update the combobox after clicking save button and doesnt closing the windows form?

Comment: The only reason that it appears that you have to close the form is that the code you have that retrieves the data from the database is only being executed when the form first loads, presumably in the `Load` event handler of the form.  If you want retrieve data from the database when the user clicks a `Button` as well then you have to execute that code in the `Click` event handler of the `Button` too.

Comment: ok sir thank you very much. I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that it appears that you have to close the form is that the code you have that retrieves the data from the database is only being executed when the form first loads, presumably in the Load event handler of the form. If you want retrieve data from the database when the user clicks a Button as well then you have to execute that code in the Click event handler of the Button too.– @jmcilhinney

Comment: Copy the same code of loading combobox from Form_load method "or" Call Form_load method in button_click event

Eg:
`Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Call Form1_Load(sender, e)
    End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

Use something like `Timer1_Tick`. A timer executes code over and over from changing the interval.